# Bring Outlookelements to front

Tags: c#, outlook, handle

I'm opening Outlookelements with the shown Code (scroll down; C# Code). Sometimes the elements don't come to front so you first have to select them. Any idea how to do this? I thought about the handle and doing this by hand.

Other idea's?

Thanks Thomas

```
MAPIFolder objFolder = new ApplicationClass().GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderNotes);
                foreach (NoteItem note in objFolder.Items)
                    note.Display(false);
```

Comment: Hi,
Where are you calling this from ? from outside outlook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling from another app you will have to handle the Hwnd, you can do this via Win API calls or you can use Redemption's [SafeInspector](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/safeinspector.htm) which which has an Handle property.

Here is a link how to get the hWnd via WinApi http://theflaker.com.ar/blog/?p=10

Comment: Thanks for advice. Can try it next week.

I'm calling this from an external program!

Comment: No worries hope it works for you, Redemption is a great lib if you work with mapi / exchange outlook etc.

Comment: Thanks, its great! Works perfectly ;) Bye